# Which Android Device should I buy for Testing Apps...?

Tags: android

I want to develop some apps on Android and I need to buy an Android Phone or Tablet for testing my apps.

Which model should I buy? 
Do you think it is better to buy a tablet directly? Just like iPad, I can test both HD and Normal apps on it easily.

Thanks.
Raymond

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android comes in numerous screen resolutions and sizes. So whatever phone you are buying you can test only for minimal number of user-group.

So buy any good phone with high hardware facilities to test functionalities. To test UI, the Android emulators will help you a lot. Create various screen size emulators and test your UI on them.

I think this link will help you to design for multiple screen sizes:

[Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Comment: Yes, I'd answer something similar. The emulator is great for verifying that the layout works for all resolutions. Still, if you're completely new to Android, it's a good idea to buy a real device just to play around with it in order to get into the minds of the users. Also, for game development, the emulator isn't always that helpful. I don't think it really matters that much what actual device you choose though.

Comment: If I buy a tablet, can I limit the app to run at a pre-defined resolution??  Just like running iPhone app on iPad. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try emulator? From my experience almost everything will work faster on Android device. Thus if something works ok on emulator it would probably work better on real device.

If you do want to buy some hardware I recommend a phone or tablet with good support from manufacturer. The device should work for a long time so it's good to be able to upgrade Android in the future. There is no sense in buying a phone with Android <= 2.3 if it has no chances for upgrades to 4.0+

Comment: yes, but most of the users are still using 2.3.3-2.3.7 according to google's statistics.

Comment: You're right. However Android is back compatile. You can set API level  of the project (for example 10 for Android 2.3.3, 2.3.4) in your IDE, so you won't be able to use new features avaible in newer APIs. That program will still work correctly on newer Android devices.